# Will SharePoint Designer 2010 work with SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I like the visual method of using SharePoint Designer 2010. I would also like to avoid using SharePoint Designer 2013 to configure WebParts using code.  Does anyone know if SharePoint Designer 2010 will work with SharePoint 2016 (online)?  Maybe I will have to learn to code but I would prefer not at this present time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it wont work with SharePoint Designer 2010 because there is a shift in the code base from 2010 to 2013.

However SharePoint Server 2016 is built on the same code base as SharePoint 2013 and the fact that you still can use SharePoint Designer 2013 on SharePoint Online, there are reasons to believe that SharePoint Designer 2013 will function very well with SharePoint Server 2016. There may be features that can’t be used, but you have other tools available such as Visual Studio, PowerShell, Browser and Design Manager.

Reference: [Ignite 2015 Announcement – There will be no SharePoint Designer 2016](http://ericoverfield.com/ignite-2015-announcement-there-will-be-no-sharepoint-designer-2016/)

To get close to visual editing, turn your head to the Design Manager.

Comment: From what I have read, the option for visual editing has been took away on SharePoint 2013 designer.  It has to be done using XSLT and xml.  Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @resolver101 True. No visual editing in SPD2013

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, you can't use SharePoint Designer 2010 with SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2016.

Although there is no SharePoint Designer 2016 But You can still use SharePoint Designer 2013 64x with SharePoint Server 2016.

The problem in Sharepoint Desinger 2013 is there is no design view because it's not support HTML 5 tag and CSS in SharePoint 2013.

also, SharePoint Server 2013 embracing new web standards for client side rendering of pages such as JavaScript, JSON, and OData, there is no longer a need to support a visual web page editor within SharePoint Designer you can check more [here](https://blogs.office.com/2012/10/10/changes-to-the-design-view-in-sharepoint-designer-2013/).

Also, you should read [SharePoint Designer 2016 and InfoPath 2016 in SharePoint Server 2016, What’s the alternatives ?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/)